# Ramps 1.4 with a power brick

Tags: ramps-1.4, arduino-mega-2650, tronxy-x1

I'm currently designing a RepRap 3D printer that will not have a heated bed. I have heard that it is possible to use a power brick with commercial printers lacking heatbeds. Is this possible with a RepRap printer using a RAMPS board?

I'm referring specifically to the TronXY X1 power brick. I was wondering if it we're possible to use the same TronXY X1 power brick with a standard RAMPS 1.4 board - rather than the special board the TronXY X1 uses.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "power brick"?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden - I had the same thought initially. I assume that the OP means something like a laptop power supply - black and brick shaped.

Comment: @Greenonline The only current answer seems to have interpreted "power brick" as "power bank". I also think it would be helpful if the question included a bit more details on why the poster thinks that such a power brick would or wouldn't work.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden By power brick, I mean a laptop power supply.

Comment: Not all laptop power supplies are created equal. Do you have using a specific supply in mind, or do you just want to know what - in general - you need to look out for?

Comment: As far as i know the RAMPS boards, they are fine without a heatbed. Just check the power (watts) of your extruder, add about 50 for the steppers and check, if your power supply can deliver the power.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I'm referring specifically to the TronXY X1 power brick. I was wondering if it we're possible to use the same TronXY X1 power brick with a standard RAMPS 1.4 board(rather than the special board the TronXY X1 uses.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you provide enough energy to heat the nozzle and keep its temperature, that is possible, as steppers power usually is limited by driver to reduce noise.

see the attached video: [A fully mobile printer example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lsx_rCCsQI)

Answer (score 1):

According to this video, [Upgrade TronXY X1 Power Supply with PC Power Supply](https://ru-clip.com/video/eOlP-YQOn5g/), which actually shows the power brick, the TronXY power brick is 12 V 5 A. The best screenshot of the brick is shown below:

[image: TronXY power brick power rating]

The narrator of the video (as do [other sources](https://makerware.thingiverse.com/groups/tronxy-x1/forums/general/topic:19203)) states that it runs extremely hot on long print cycles.

An example replacement power supply, on AliExpress, [Tronxy 3D printer accessoires power supply 240W AC110/220V DC 12V 20A for 3D print DIY kit part](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Tronxy-3D-printer-accessoires-power-supply-240W-AC110-220V-DC-12V-20A-for-3D-print-DIY/32723053329.html), is rated at 20 A.

So, in theory any 12 V 10-15+ A rated laptop power brick should suffice.

However, that was not your question. As a [*standard* RAMPS board also runs at 12 V](https://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.4#Power_Supply), then yes, you can use the TronXY power brick with a standard RAMPS board.

Nevertheless, would you want to? It would seem advisable to get a higher rated power brick<sup>1</sup>. That way, you can run the printer harder and longer without the risk of the power supply dying (or worse, catching fire) and if, at a later stage, you want to add a heated bed, then you'll be able to use the same supply brick.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think the biggest laptop 12 V supply I've seen was 15 A on eBay. Earler Xbox 360 bricks go up to 16.5 A. Both of these still get rather warm, due to their (admittedly convenient) black plastic casing.  It might be better to get a standard, well ventilated, aluminium cased 20-35 A LED power supply, as in the AliExpress link above.